# Second order degenerate perturbation theory for a 4-level system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

I am trying to find the second-order energy correction for a perturbation to a 4-level system
$$H = H_0 + \lambda V.$$
I only care about corrections to the lowest energy, which is non-degenerate, however, the other eigenvalues of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$ are all degenerate. The spectral decomposition of the unperturbed problem can be computed as
$$H_0 = E_0^{(0)}|\psi_0^{(0)} \rangle \langle \psi_0^{(0)}|+ E_1^{(0)} \sum_{j=1}^3|\psi_j^{(0)} \rangle \langle \psi_j^{(0)}|,$$
with $\langle \psi_j^{(0)} |\psi_k^{(0)} \rangle = \delta_{jk}$. I understand that one must diagonalize the $3 \times 3$ matrix $W_{ij} =\langle \psi_i^{(0)}|V |\psi_j^{(0)} \rangle $ to compute the first order correction to the degenerate eigenvalues, however, I am looking for the corrections to the lowest energy $E_0^{(0)}$ which is non-degenerate. How to I compute the first and second order corrections in this case where there is "mixed" degenerate and non-degenerate sectors?

Comment: For the lowest state, you can just apply non-degenerate perturbation theory as usual.  Ideally, use the $\psi_0^{(0)}$ and the states that you get from diagonalizing $W_{ij}$ as your basis.

Comment: @march Here $W_{ij}$ is a $3 \times 3$ matrix, whereas the eigenstates are part of a $4$ dimensional Hilbert space, how would I calculate inner-products between the two?